# Clojure vector -> vector function using # and % syntax sugar?

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to code using #, %1, %2 for the below?

```
(defn fib-step [[a b]]
  [b (+ a b)])

(defn fib-seq []
  (map first (iterate fib-step [0 1])))

user> (take 20 (fib-seq))
(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181)
```

In short, I'd like to know how to write
 vector -> vector function using # and % syntax sugar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
(def step #(-> [(% 1) (+ (% 0) (% 1))]))
(def fib #(map first (iterate step [0 1])))

(println 
 (take 20 (fib))
)
```

or

```
(def step #(-> [(% 1) (+ (% 0) (% 1))]))
(def fib (->> [0 1]
              (iterate step)
              (map first)))

(println
  (->> fib 
       (take 20))
))
```

Comment: (memo) iterate は関数＝写像を漸化式(数学的構造)として引数にとり、無限リスト=ストリームに展開する関数。

Comment: step（漸化式）による無限ストリームということは計算ステップ軸上の無限リスト

Answer (score 3):

You can easily produce a vector using the `#()` reader form with the `->` threading macro. For example, the following two functions are equivalent:

```
(fn [a b] [b a])
#(-> [%2 %])
```

However, if you need to do destructuring, as in your case, you're best off just sticking with one of the `fn` forms with an explicit parameter list. The best you'd get with `#()` is something like this:

```
#(-> [(% 1) (+ (% 0) (% 1))])
```

or

```
#(-> [(% 1) (apply + %)])
```

Using the higher-order [`juxt`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/juxt) function is another nice way to create vectors, but unfortunately in this case it doesn't buy you much either:

```
(def fib-step (juxt second #(apply + %)))
```

I think out of all the options, using `fn` is still the best fit because of its easy support for destructuring:

```
(fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making `fib-step` take 2 parameters rather than a vector as that would make things more clear that this function need two values whereas a vector as param means it can take any number of values as param (in the form of the vector).

```
(def fib-step #(-> [%2 (+ %1 %2)]))

(defn fib-seq []
  (map first (iterate (partial apply fib-step) [0 1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `vector` function is clearer than the `(-> [...])` "trick":

```
#(vector (% 1) (apply + %))
```

Though in this instance, with destructuring, I'd just use a named function or `(fn [...] ...)`  anyway.